# Simple Shell that can exit and change directories using execvp and fork

Tags: c, shell

I'm creating a simple shell program for an operating systems class

we are only allowed to use printf,fgets,strcmp,chdir,fork,wait,and execvp

the issue i have been having is changing the directory and getting ls and ls-l work

This is the full program

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_LEN 1024
void  parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
     while (*line != '\0') {
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0';
          *argv++ = line;
          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
               line++;
     }
     *argv = NULL;
}


int main(){
    char line[BUFFER_LEN];  //get command line
    char* argv[100];        //user command

    while(1){
        printf("Timmy>> ");

        fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, stdin);
        parse(line, argv);

        if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0){            //check if command is exit
                break;
        }
        else if(strcmp(line, "cd")==0){         //checks if command is cd
                chdir(*argv);
        }
        else{
                int pid= fork();           //fork child
                if(pid==0){                //Child
                        execvp(*argv, argv);
                        printf("could not do process\n");}
                else{                      //Parent
                        wait(NULL);}
        }
   }
        return 0;
}
```

the expected result is to list all files and to be able to change directories I believe my issue is with the parse function and the argv array

Comment: Please create a [mre] with (1) a full program that we can run; (2) the input you're typing; (3) the expected behavior; and (4) the actual behavior. Show us the output and error messages.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, I added the full program and the errors I've been getting tell me its an argv array error

Comment: Is `could not do process` a useful error message?

Comment: You are passing too many argument.  Consider the case where the user just hits return.  In parse, you get a single newline, and you wind up passing an empty argument.  Try `*--argv = NULL`

Comment: that worked thank you so much William, still working on changing the directory but I have an idea of what I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decrement `argv` before assigning NULL in parse.  Just do `*--argv = NULL` at the end of `parse`.  To fix `cd`,  `chdir(argv[1])`.  Also, deal with a closed stdin.  The user should be able to exit the shell either by explicitly typing `exit` or by closing stdin.  That is, break when `fgets` returns NULL.  Also:

```
execvp(*argv, argv);
perror(*argv);
```

Error messages should be informative.